# Error al clonar una aplicación desplegada: Hostname: Name or service not known

Tags: git, ssh

todavía estoy tratando de implementar mi aplicación Python en el servidor de la universidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me dicen que mi aplicación ha sido creada. Pero, por un lado, [no puedo acceder a él](http://qmulpython35-moodbot.apps.devcloud.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/) y, por otro, cuando intento instalar herramientas para realizar cambios en el código, es decir, para instalar el cliente Git para su sistema operativo, y desde su comando línea obtengo este error :

```
Hostname qmulpython35-moodbot.apps.devcloud.eecs.qmul.ac.uk: Name or service not known
```

Aquí está el error completo:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa$ git clone ssh://5b2bd483251c089a9600001b@qmulpython35-moodbot.apps.devcloud.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~/git/qmulpython35.git/
Cloning into 'qmulpython35'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname qmulpython35-moodbot.apps.devcloud.eecs.qmul.ac.uk: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Aquí está mi versión de git :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~$ git --version
git version 2.7.4
```

Comment: Ya revisaste si tienes instalado git? `git --version` por otro lado instalaste la ssh-keygen en el servidor de tu escuela para que puedas acceder mediante ssh?

Comment: @Cig Si, tengo git. Pero ne sé para ssh-keygen, solo soy un estudiante al que se le ha pedido que implemente un sitio web. La única clave que creé era la interfaz de GitHub.

Comment: en el error "sh: Could not resolve hostname qmulpython35-moodbot.apps.devcloud.eecs.qmul.ac.uk: Name or service not known
" te dice que ese host no es accesible desde el equipo en el que ejecutas el comando. He hecho un ping a ese host y no responde, y un nmap y tampoco me lo resuelve...